# adding text to image using python

Tags: python

Is the following function correct, this code is meant to add a phrase to image. Note that i cannot use image.text function or any other but can only use getpixel, putpixel, load, and save.

```
def insertTxtImage(srcImage, phrase):
    pixel = srcImage.getpixel(30,30);
    srcImage.putpixel(pixel,phrase);
    srcImage.save;
pass
```

Yes it is homework which can only use getpixel, putpixel, load, and save to insert a phrase in to the image.

I tried to do this with this code but it is giving system error (argument is not a tuple)

def insertTxtImage(srcImage, phrase):
    pix = srcImage.load()
    pix[0,0] = phrase
    srcImage.save()
 pass

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Please be more clear. What sort of object is `srcImage` that it has `getpixel`, `putpixel` and `save`? What do they *do*? Perhaps this is part of `PIL`?

Comment: You have the code and the images, have you run it?  What does it do?  I'm guessing it doesn't do what you want, since you are here asking about it.

Comment: "can only use"?  @user, if this is homework, that's OK, but _please_ tag it clearly as such in this case, otherwise the Q is likely to be closed.  Also, those semicolons are useless, so is that stand-alone `pass`, and you're *not* **calling** the `save` method.  And, wouldn't `putPixel` want one more arg, the _coordinate_ of the pixel to "put", whatever framework you're using?  How else does it know *where* to put it -- mind-reading?  So that's 2 serious bugs and 4 useless-remove-them things in 5 lines, and we aren't at the meat of it yet...!-)

Answer (score -1):

No, the functions you are using modify pixels.

To draw font you want to use something like following:

```
f= pygame.font.Font(None, 12)
surf= f.render(phrase)
srcImage.blit(surf, (30,30))
```

for more documentation see here: (scroll down a bit)
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

**EDIT:** nvm, I don't even know what you're doing or trying to do